Xcode 15.3 is debugging older iOS executable
Update:
Not sure why the negative votes are for as the problem is legit. I have found a similar thread on apple developer forums posted very recently by some other developer. The issue seem to be related to the mac os version 14.4 by the looks of it.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/748084
--
I have run into a very strange problem with Xcode 15.3 for iOS projects and was wondering if anyone has encountered this issue and has a solution.
What happens is when I debug, it is still launching and executing the previously cleaned and rebuilt version on the mac so essentially any code changes I've done isn't working. Every time I do a code change, I have to manually go to product -> clean build folder and re run the project to get the expected changes.
This happens when I debug on M series mac under destination "My Mac (Designed for iPhone / iPad)" only. If I deploy it to a physical device, everything seem to work alright.
Swift Compiler Compilation Mode is set to "incremental" for debug under Xcode which is what it used to be all this time. This problem started to occur from about 2-3 weeks ago without any updates to the software system (xcode / cli / etc..) and it can reproduced on any existing project or a new project I create.

I just did a quick test with a simple iOS / Swift / UIKit app. Using Xcode 15.3 on macOS 14.4.1 I had no problem running the Mac (Designed for iPad) app on my Mac. I then changed a line of code for a view color and ran again. The new color appeared. No need to do a clean build first. Do you see your issue with a new project or just your existing one?

Both existing projects and new projects have the same fate for me since 2-3 weeks ago sadly.

@HangarRash i found a similar issue posted very recently on apple developer forums. https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/748084  Looks like I'm not the only one facing it.

This turns out to be a mac os issue introduced from around 14.4.1 release. As of Mac OS 14.5 the issue was addressed according to the release notes.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-14_5-release-notes#Mac-Designed-for-iPad-Apps
Resolved Issues
Fixed: macOS might launch the wrong version for (Designed for iPad) apps after double clicking the icon or after building from Xcode. (121404522)
